# Show that weighted $L^2$-norm is not equivalent to $L^2$-norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Given $\phi(x) = 4x(1-x)$ I need to show that $\vert\vert \sqrt \phi\cdot\vert\vert_{L^2((0, 1))}$ is not equivalent to $\vert\vert \cdot\vert\vert_{L^2((0, 1))}$ on $L^2((0, 1))$.

I know that this can be done either by showing that there are no constants $c, C$:

$c\vert\vert\cdot\vert\vert_{L^2((0, 1))} \leq \vert\vert \sqrt \phi\cdot\vert\vert_{L^2((0, 1))} \leq C\vert\vert\cdot\vert\vert_{L^2((0, 1))}$

(Constant $C$ exists and is 1, but I can't show that $c$ does not exist)

or by finding a sequence that converges in one norm but does not converge in the other.

I would appreciate any hints or other help regarding this problem.

Comment: Let $f_n = \xi_{[0,1/n]}$. So that $c > 0$ cannot exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the functions $f_n(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\chi_{[\frac1n,1]}(x)$.They are in $L^2(0,1)$, but their $L^2$ norms explodes, while the weighted one does not since the square roots cancel.